# Error while executing IronRuby with bewildr

Tags: ruby, ironruby

I am trying to automate a WPF using Bewildr, cucumber and IronRuby.
As of now, as a baby step I have done the following

Installed IronRuby1.1 in C:\IronRuby
Installed Bewildr and cucumber gem

Created a Ruby file in IronRuby bin
**sample.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'    
require 'bewildr'    
@app, @main_window = Bewildr::Application.start_app_and_wait_for_window("C:\\Documents and Settings\\321106\\Desktop\\ExpenseItStandalone.exe", /App v1.\d+/)
```

When i execute it in cmd prompt using

```
ruby sample.rb
```

I get the following error:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bewildr-0.1.14/lib/bewildr.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': Bewildr only works under IronRuby (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from adding_steps.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run bewildr in plain ruby. You need to use IronRuby. Instead of:

```
ruby sample.rb
```

Try:

```
ir sample.rb
```

Comment: I realised the ir.exe was in a different path. Now ir.exe and the program reside in the same folder but I still get an error like this      unknown: no such file to load -- gem_prelude.rb (LoadError)

Comment: Now a new error:  >>> require 'minitest' C:/Program Files/IronRuby 1.1/Lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `r equire': no such file to load -- minitest (LoadError)fromC:/Program Files/IronRuby1.1/Lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require' from (ir):1